# OpenGL vertex shader precision issues

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, glsl, shader

I'm trying to make a vertex shader that will make the screen wiggle, like it was made of waves. This is fine, except that I didn't realize that vertex shaders were in fact by vertices, when soing 2D as well, I thought it was by pixels.

This means that a large sprite, will only wiggle in the top and buttom, whereas I would like it to wiggle all the way down, is there any way to make it use more vertices on a given sprite? Except for chopping up the sprite that is?

Note: I'm using ´libgx´ in java.

Here's the shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform float off = 0.0f;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
varying vec4 pos;

void main() {
    vColor = a_color;
    vTexCoord = a_texCoord0;
    pos = a_position;
    pos.x = pos.x + sin(pos.y/10+off)*10;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * pos;
}
```

[image: shader tester]

as you can see the text waves very nicely, because theyr y coordinates are close, but the sprites should wave multiple times, but are unable to do so, because of the lack of vetors.

Comment: You're right, 1 second, I just didn't think it was too applicable to this question, but I'll throw the shader in anyway ^^

Comment: I can upload images? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Subdivide the sprites geometry*

From what I see you are trying to do transformations on the vertex program. It does actually move only vertices so you control 4 points here. Therefore you will not have the wiggle effect you wanted.

## Fragment Shader Solution

One of the solutions is to do the effect on the fragment shader and transform the texture coords. But you will have to increase the sprite size by some padding margin that will display the displacement.

I think you might get the most optimal solution with this because you don't need to pass additional geometry then.

```
gl_FragColor = 
texture2D(myTexture, 
  vec2(gl_TexCoord[0].x + 0.1 * sin(gl_TexCoord[0].y * 10), gl_TexCoord[0].y));
```

[image: Fragment shader implementation]

## Geometry Solution

The second solution is to not have a single quad as a sprite but a subdivided vertically quad stack.
[image: 10 Quads]
[image: 30 Quads]

### Problem Explanation image

[image: explanation]

Comment: Yeah, I kinda got that it was because there's only 4 vertices ^^ So you mean I should do this as a polygon with multiple quads? And then use the sprite as a texture for that polygon?

Comment: nice fragment shader solution, too. care to provide an image as well?

Comment: I've added the Shader snippet. Should be sufficient for an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that answer was great, but can I ask, which of the solutions will have the highest performance?

Comment: I think that the fragment shader solution would be the fastest one  from the two proposed.